# DAG runs stuck in running state using Azure Data Factory Managed Airflow (version 2.4.3)

Tags: airflow, azure-data-factory

I'm following Microsoft's tutorial on [how does managed airflow work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-does-managed-airflow-work) using the tutorial.py script referenced in the documentation (see code block below). I've set up my airflow environment in azure data factory using the same configuration in the documentation with the exception of the airflow version - I'm using version 2.4.3 as version 2.2.2 is no longer available in data factory.

Everything appears to be set up successfully. However, my DAG runs never succeed nor fail they just stay in the running state
[dag monitor image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKSAf.png)

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from textwrap import dedent

# The DAG object; we'll need this to instantiate a DAG
from airflow import DAG

# Operators; we need this to operate!
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
with DAG(
    "tutorial",
    # These args will get passed on to each operator
    # You can override them on a per-task basis during operator initialization
    default_args={
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "email": ["airflow@example.com"],
        "email_on_failure": False,
        "email_on_retry": False,
        "retries": 1,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
        # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
        # 'pool': 'backfill',
        # 'priority_weight': 10,
        # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
        # 'wait_for_downstream': False,
        # 'sla': timedelta(hours=2),
        # 'execution_timeout': timedelta(seconds=300),
        # 'on_failure_callback': some_function,
        # 'on_success_callback': some_other_function,
        # 'on_retry_callback': another_function,
        # 'sla_miss_callback': yet_another_function,
        # 'trigger_rule': 'all_success'
    },
    description="A simple tutorial DAG",
    schedule=timedelta(minutes=5),
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["example"],
) as dag:

    # t1, t2 and t3 are examples of tasks created by instantiating operators
    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="print_date",
        bash_command="date",
    )

    t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id="sleep",
        depends_on_past=False,
        bash_command="sleep 5",
        retries=3,
    )
    t1.doc_md = dedent(
        """\
    #### Task Documentation
    You can document your task using the attributes `doc_md` (markdown),
    `doc` (plain text), `doc_rst`, `doc_json`, `doc_yaml` which gets
    rendered in the UI's Task Instance Details page.
    ![img](http://montcs.bloomu.edu/~bobmon/Semesters/2012-01/491/import%20soul.png)
    **Image Credit:** Randall Munroe, [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/license.html)
    """
    )

    dag.doc_md = __doc__  # providing that you have a docstring at the beginning of the DAG; OR
    dag.doc_md = """
    This is a documentation placed anywhere
    """  # otherwise, type it like this
    templated_command = dedent(
        """
    {% for i in range(5) %}
        echo "{{ ds }}"
        echo "{{ macros.ds_add(ds, 7)}}"
    {% endfor %}
    """
    )

    t3 = BashOperator(
        task_id="templated",
        depends_on_past=False,
        bash_command=templated_command,
    )

    t1 >> [t2, t3]
```

I've tested this locally and the runs succeed so I'm wondering if there's any additional configuration required for azure data factory managed airflow that isn't documented in the tutorial link referenced above? Are there certain Airflow requirements or Airflow configuration overrides that need to be set when using azure data factory's managed airflow service?

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on your first question. Airflow in ADF is a new feature as it is currently in preview, and as with every new feature you might sometimes run into errors.

For this problem I think more backend information is required why they get stuck in running state, so the best action to take is to create a support ticket with ADF and see what they can provide from the backend.

Comment: Thanks Ziya! Makes sense. Will try my luck with msft directly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ADF Managed Airflow had an outage with Airflow v2.4.3 where DAGs remained stuck in a "running" state. Looks like this was only for a short period so it should be working now